# The usage of “@class” keyword in Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I was trying to understand the usage of "@class" keyword in Omnet++, what is the "@class" keyword uses in Omnet++? What is the use of the input parameter of @class? If I don't use of @class keyword, what problems are occurred? For example, in the following code:

```
simple UDPBasicAppNew extends UDPBasicApp
{
    parameters:

        @class(UDPBasicAppNew);
        int numberOfMessages = default(10000000);
}
```

If the line "@class(UDPBasicAppNew);" is removed, what problems are occurred?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming that you read the related documentation in the OMNeT++ manual (simple module), what is your actual question? What part of the manual is not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:inheritance):

> IMPORTANT
> When you extend a simple module type both in NED and in C++, you must use the `@class` property to tell NED to use the new C++ class -- otherwise the new module type inherits the C++ class of the base!

It means that if one declares `UDPBasicAppNew` as:

```
simple UDPBasicAppNew extends UDPBasicApp {
  parameters:
    int numberOfMessages;
}
```

the C++ class named `UDPBasicApp` will be used for `UDPBasicAppNew`.

However, if one declares `UDPBasicAppNew` this way:

```
simple UDPBasicAppNew extends UDPBasicApp {
  parameters:
    @class(UDPBasicAppNew);
    int numberOfMessages;
}
```

the C++ class named `UDPBasicAppNew` will be used for `UDPBasicAppNew`.